# Sort to optimize manager assignment in excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, optimization

I currently have a list of employees by region, area & branch (in that order). Every row represents a branch & the number of employees that branch have.

I want to calculate how many managers I will need to manage all these branches.

I know that one manager can only manage up to 40 employees.

Additionally, the managers can only manage branches in the same region.

I am looking for a way to sort the list so that I can minimize the number of managers I will need.

Thank you

Comment: Please include the code you are working on to solve this in your question, and explain what problems you are having with it.

Comment: Dear braX, I currently do not have any code in mind yet. This question is more of understanding whether this is even feasible with excel or VBA. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't a pivot table solve your problem? You can play with your data and get the results. Only thing you need is to mix managers and employees with an auxiliar column which tells you if the employee is manager or worker.